# unexpected EOF error while running bash_profile

Tags: bash, bashrc

I am trying to install a software in my university cluster via ssh login from my PC. 
So, I first login via ssh, and then according to the software documentation I add the following lines in my `bash_profile`:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

export PRIMAL="/projects/imputation_fam/primal"
export APPS="/projects/imputation_fam/apps"
source /projects/imputation_fam/primal/system/dots/bash_profile
```

But when I try to run the `~/.bash_profile` after the above editing, I get the following error:

```
--bash: /homes/user/.bashrc: line 10: unexpected EOF while looking for   matching `"'
--bash: /homes/user/.bashrc: line 12: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Edit: The .bashrc file

```
  # .bashrc

  # Source global definitions
     if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
         . /etc/bashrc
     fi

  # User specific aliases and functions
     umask u=rwx,g=rwx,o=
     "
```

Comment: Add line 10 and 12 of your `~/.bash_profile` to your question.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: I edited my question completely. Hopefully it will help.

Comment: The error messages refer to `.bashrc`, not `.bash_profile` (`/homes/user/.bashrc: line 10:` and `/homes/user/.bashrc: line 12:`) - you need to post that as well.

Comment: I added the .bashrc file above

Comment: Crosspost http://stackoverflow.com/q/33600996/3789550

Comment: Seriously?  You have an error message that says `looking for matching "`, and you've got a line with a single `"` on it, and you need to ask for help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the trailing quote in your `.bashrc`.

It should look like the following:

```
# .bashrc
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
     . /etc/bashrc
fi
# User specific aliases and functions
umask u=rwx,g=rwx,o=
```